# How to deal with header names changing in CSV data source?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Will make this short and sweet - we have a massive .CSV that we are linking to PBI Desktop.  Some of the header names in this .CSV were not optimal and have since been updated by the SQL backend.  However, PBI is not happy with not being able to find the exact header that existed previously, and we could not find a route by which to tell the software that a header name had changed.  Is there a quick solution for this?

Comment: Wish I could give you both credit - each option works!  Thanks for the lesson!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick.. Not so much. Easy? Relatively.

You'll need to manually edit the PowerQuery in the Advanced Query side.

I recommend un-hiding the formula bar in the Query Editor and going step by step through the applied steps. Once you find a broken step, check out the PowerQuery, you'll see your no longer existent fields there as plain text in the formula bar ( or advanced editor view ). Swap out the old field names in the PowerQuery with the new names and you should be golden.

You might even get away with a few find/replaces..

Answer (score 3):

Here is an idea to work around this issue,

as long as your header are changing, I recommend you to do these step in power query:

1. search on your power query the step where the headers are promoted
2. instead of this step, delete the first row (the one containing the headers)
3. Then add a step renaming the header as desired

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this if you delete your top rows in your first row operation in query editor. This way the CODE of your power BI query will not contain a specific name and will name your columns: 'column 1' ; 'column 2' etc.etc.

You can now edit to your own demands and when you change datasource nothing will go in error.

Hope this helps for people who are also looking into the problem.